# Results Viewer stays minimized

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

In a machine I have UFT 11.51 with Results Viewer 11.51 and when I run the Results Viewer it stays minimized i.e I cannot view the results.

I use Windows 7 and have change the theme to XP just to try out if it is a graphical glitch...

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Mateo

Answer (score 2):

Similar issue I was also facing but finally it got resolved by following below steps

1. Mouse Hover the result viewer on Task Bar
2. Right click on the RR popup.
3. Click on the Maximize option.

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to close the result viewer and launch the result viewer from QTP toolbar icon.
This seems to work for me.

Comment: It does not for me... getting desperate now... Thanks anyways Shatz ;) I mean I did uninstall the results viewer and installed again (trying as well when downgraded at 11.50).

Answer (score 0):

Whether the QTP icon is showing on the taskbar, but the window can not be opened? If so, try below three steps.
1. Uninstall Result Viewer 11.51.
2. Install a lower version, like Result Viewer 11.0. Open one result report using the lower version, you can always see it is minimized there, set it to maxmize, close.
3. Reinstall to Result Viewer 11.51, run again.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks Kun Liu but I have already tried this... there is no way. I accepted it and I still consult the HTML results file ;) hopeless... ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird solution. Same thing was happening to me and I ended up creating another user with administrator rights on my machine. I haven't had problems with running that new account.

Comment: i do have admin rights but i also understand that when creating another user you have all settings by default and other thinngs that "have changed" back to the original... in any case in company´s equipment it might be more difficult to do this... thanks though Jon ;)

Answer (score 0):

**It is not minimized. It is sized in a way that it is completely offscreen.**

Try focussing the results viewer (by Alt-Tabbing to it), then push Alt-Space, and select "move". Then use the cursor keys -- the window will be scrolled into view if you arrowkey into the right direction.

This can happen if you switch from dual- to single-display config.

Comment: Thanks BlastOne but this is not the case. The Alt-Tab method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just Press `Alt+ Space` then select move. This is valid for all minimized window problems.